# How to get rails to parse a url with a hashbang?

Tags: ruby-on-rails, angularjs

I have an incoming url that looks like this (due to my AngularJS configuration):

```
/new_query#?query=somequery
```

If the hashbang (#) hadn't been there, Rails would parse it correctly, and extract the query parameter into the params variable. However, it doesn't seem to successfully extract the params when the hashbang is there.

Is there any standard way / config to solve this?

Or would I have to monkey patch some parameter parsing code in rails, by i.e. making a regular expression to find the # and remove it from the url string?

Comment: Can you dump the params hash and post it?

Comment: The fragment part of the URL doesn't even reach the server.

Comment: @Mohamad: The params hash looks like this: {"action"=>"search_from_url", "controller"=>"admin/seeks"}

Comment: @GergoErdosi Ah.. but how would it then be possible (in hashbang mode) for users to share links between each other?

Comment: I just learned that the only way to share links then would be for the server to render a page with some JS that interprets everything after the hashbang, and reroutes (i.e. angular routing) to the correct page. (The browser doesn't remove the part after the hashbang on the first request, it just doesn't send it). Correct me if I'm wrong.

Comment: Yeah, generally with this sort of url, JS on the page will read it and make a (usually AJAX) request to the server.  This allows users to deeplink to pages which pull in their content after initial pageload.

Comment: How did you get to this URL?  I mean, what generated it?

Comment: @MaxWilliams Angular generated the part after the #.